# Change color of cell in Grid (Vaadin)

Tags: vaadin

I am using `BeanItemContainer` in `Grid` to display my data. I need to color each cell separately, depending on the data in the cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [section about the Grid](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.grid.html#components.grid.renderer) in the Book of Vaadin explains this in the subsection *Generating Cell Styles*:

> You set a `CellStyleGenerator` to a grid with `setCellStyleGenerator()`. The `getStyle()` method gets a `CellReference`, which contains various information about the cell and a reference to the grid, and should return a style name or `null` if no style is generated.
>
> For example, to add a style name to a specific column, you can match on the property ID of the column as follows:
>
> ```
> grid.setCellStyleGenerator(cellRef -> // Java 8
>     "born".equals(cellRef.getPropertyId())?
>         "rightalign" : null);
> ```
>
> You could then style the cells with a CSS rule as follows:
>
> ```
> .v-grid-cell.rightalign {
>     text-align: right;
> }
> ```

Comment: Great! Can u please explain where I need to declare CSS rule?

Comment: @Jumper the best place is the theme.

Comment: Im using "valo" theme. I placed your css declaration in file (path) src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/valo/styles.scss . Tell me please why css still dont work?

Comment: Solution is creating your own theme

Answer (score 1):

Where is one more way, 100% dynamical, without style files.

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<MyObj> of("<div style$=\"background-color: [[item.color]];\">[[item.duration]]</div>")
  .withProperty("color", MyObj::getDurationColor)
  .withProperty("duration", MyObj::getDurationMin)).setHeader("Duration");
```

In this case color will be more intensive as duration time increases.

```
public String getDurationColor() {
    long latency = durationMin;
    if (latency > 255) latency = 255;
    return "#ff" + Long.toHexString(255-latency) + Long.toHexString(255-latency);
}
```