# Coloring cells in Vaadin Grid that uses OpenCSV

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am attempting conditional coloring/formatting for a Vaadin Grid that sources its data from a file (using OpenCSV) rather than a POJO. I was looking at [Change color of cell in Grid (Vaadin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843850/change-color-of-cell-in-grid-vaadin) to see if this could be modified to support CSV instead, but have so far come up empty.

Can this be done with the cell style generator method? I am referencing https://vaadin.com/blog/read-and-display-a-csv-file-in-java for the reading of the csv data.

Comment: Yes, this can be done like this or with a LitRenderer. What have you tried so far? What's your actual problem? Is there a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Here's a sample of the classnamegenerator feature in the Grid documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#styling-rows-and-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the CSVReader and Vaadin documentation examples with the generic Person class, you can do something like:

```
grid.addColumn(str->str[columnIndex])
.setKey(header)
.setHeader(header)
.setClassNameGenerator(str -> {
    if (Integer.valueOf(str[columnIndex]) > 8){
        return "condition1";
    }
                            
    if (Integer.valueOf(str[columnIndex]) < 8){
        return "condition2";
    }
                            
    return null;
});
```

Similar to what is done in the cookbook example, you can then define those conditions in the corresponding css file.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at the questions/blogs from different versions; the SO
question is about Vaadin 8 - the blog about Vaadin Flow (10 and up, but
most likely v14 in this case).

Styling rows and/or columns is documented in the Grid:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#styling-rows-and-columns

> You can style individual cells based on the data, for example, to
> highlight changes or important information.
>
> ...
>
> ```java
> grid.setClassNameGenerator(person -> {
>     if (person.getRating() >= 8)
>         return "high-rating";
>     if (person.getRating() <= 4)
>         return "low-rating";
>     return null;
> });
> ```

Note: there is also `setClassNameGenerator` for `Column`.